# SSRS data-driven subscriptions saving pdf file on the parameter value passed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS 2008 R2 report, with a parameter employeeID. When we do the data driven subscription I am exporting the report into a PDF file.

The PDF is saved/generated as reportname.pdf by default.Can we save the pdf as reportparameter.pdf.

Example:If we have an employeeID as 223,can the PDF generated for that emoloyeeID be saved as 223.pdf.

Does SSRS support this scenario when the method of delivery is through email ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way save the filename as you indicate would be using the ssrs api. You can't save to another filename using the subscription service as it will use the report name as the filename :(

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check out Boomerang Notification Services for SQL server from [Fuel9](http://fuel9.com). The framework is easy to use and you can among other things control each file name. I think I have some sample code (tsql) doing just this so let me know if you interested and I'll see if I can dig it up for you.

Cheers,

/M